# Can tail recursion support shorten the stack for other function calls?

Tags: recursion, tail-recursion

Can languages that support tail recursion apply the same technique to non-recursive function calls?

For example, if the last thing that function `foo` does is return the value of calling `bar`, might the language discard `foo`'s stack frame? Are any languages known to actually do this?

Comment: I'm thinking about this because of Ruby's Rack library (though most Ruby implementations don't support tail recursion); often a Rack middleware's last action is to call the next middleware, and it would be nice if that memory could be freed.

Comment: I would say that depends on the compiler and the language. But if the called functions are all end-recursive. I guess, a compiler could inline the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can. For example, consider the following C code:

```
int f();
int g() { return f(); }
```

When I compile this using `gcc 4.6.3` with `-O3` on `x86-64`, I get the following assembly for `g()`:

```
g:
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        jmp     f              ; <==== unconditional jump to f
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the concrete example.

Answer (score 2):

[Erlang does](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/recursion):

> Tail recursion as seen here is not making the memory grow because when
>   the virtual machine sees a function calling itself in a tail position
>   (the last expression to be evaluated in a function), it eliminates the
>   current stack frame. This is called tail-call optimisation (TCO) and
>   it is a special case of a more general optimisation named Last Call
>   Optimisation (LCO).
>
> LCO is done whenever the last expression to be evaluated in a function
>   body is another function call. When that happens, as with TCO, the
>   Erlang VM avoids storing the stack frame. As such tail recursion is
>   also possible between multiple functions. As an example, the chain of
>   functions a() -> b(). b() -> c(). c() -> a(). will effectively create
>   an infinite loop that won't go out of memory as LCO avoids overflowing
>   the stack. This principle, combined with our use of accumulators is
>   what makes tail recursion useful.