# Why does this overflow the stack instead of using tail recursion?

Tags: clojure

I've defined the following functions in Clojure.

```
; return the input unchanged
(defn same [x] x)

; Recursively call the function on the input N times
(defn recurse-n-times [input function n]
  (if (= n 0)
    input
    (recurse-n-times (function input) function (- n 1))
  )
)
```

Here are some outputs from my recursion function:

```
(recurse-n-times 0 inc 5)     ; returns 5, as expected
(recurse-n-times 0 same 5)    ; returns 0, as expected
(recurse-n-times 0 same 5000) ; StackOverflowError:
                              ; clojure.lang.Numbers$LongOps.combine
                              ; (Numbers.java:394)
```

I don't understand why I get a `StackOverflowError`. The last thing that `recurse-n-times` does is call itself, so I expect it to use tail recursion and not grow the stack at all.

I **would** expect this alternate definition to give a `StackOverflowError`:

```
(defn bad-recurse-n-times [input function n]
  (if (= n 0)
    input
    (function (alt-recurse-n-times input function (- n 1)))
  )
)
```

Why does `recurse-n-times` not use tail recursion?

Comment: Hmmmm, if within `recurse-n-times` I call `recur` instead of `recurse-n-times`, it works.

Comment: Also, if I try that trick in `bad-recurse-n-times` I get `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can only recur from tail position`

Comment: Also worth noting, if you need non-recursive (or multi-function-chain recursive) tail call elimination, you can convert your code to use trampoline.

Comment: If you think that you got your answer, kindly pick one!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a limitation of the JVM, not of Clojure. JVM doesn't support TCO.

Clojure offers a special form for this, [recur](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--%28recur%20exprs*%29)

```
(defn recurse-n-times [input function n]
  (if (= n 0)
  input
  (recur (function input) function (- n 1))))

(recurse-n-times 0 same 500000) ;; will work
```

recur form should appear at the tail position otherwise the Clojure compiler will complain about it.

> Note that recur is the only non-stack-consuming looping construct in Clojure. There is no tail-call optimization and the use of self-calls for looping of unknown bounds is discouraged. recur is functional and its use in tail-position is verified by the compiler.

Comment: I guess that means that TCO when calling a different function isn't possible in Clojure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593540/can-tail-recursion-support-shorten-the-stack-for-other-function-calls

Comment: @NathanLong Adapt your program to use `trampoline`. There is a nice example [here](http://jakemccrary.com/blog/2010/12/06/trampolining-through-mutual-recursion/). Note that `trampoline` only copes with mutual *tail* recursion.

Answer (score 4):

According to [clojure.org](http://clojure.org/lisps)

> There is no tail-call optimization, use recur.

So you must use "recur" special form to do that.

Comment: recur isn't a keyword, it is a special form.